Error Deploying React App to GitHub Pages: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
I created a React app using Vite and developed it locally in Visual Studio Code. After completing the project, I initiated a local Git repository and pushed the files to GitHub. I configured the deployment using the gh-pages package and added the necessary settings in package.json, including setting the base URL. However, when I deployed the app using npm run deploy and accessed the live preview link on GitHub Pages, I encountered a blank white page with the following error in the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I've checked the base URL and ensured that it matches the repository name. I'm not sure what's causing this issue or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I checked the links for CSS, JavaScript, and images in my project, and they seemed fine. But when I tried to view my React app on GitHub Pages, I only saw a blank screen and got an error saying,
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.

I'm not sure what's causing this problem or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

I was experiencing the same problem, and deploying using GitHub Actions with the steps provided here solved the issue.
